# How cann I access/send data to MainActivity from WebView Cordova AngularJS controller?

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova

how can I send data from the angularjs controller to MainActivity in Android Studio.

This is MainActivity:

```js
package at.restaurantKellner;

import android.os.Bundle;
import org.apache.cordova.*;

public class MainActivity extends CordovaActivity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // enable Cordova apps to be started in the background
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null && extras.getBoolean("cdvStartInBackground", false)) {
            moveTaskToBack(true);
        }

        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
        loadUrl(launchUrl);
    }
}
```

This is my Angular controller.js:

```js
'use strict';
window.App.Module = angular.module('AppModule.tisch-details', ['ngRoute']);

window.App.Ctrls.controller('tisch-detailsCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$timeout', '$route', '$rootScope', 'ngDialog', 'czs', '$sce', '$q', 'user', function ($scope, $http, $location, $timeout, $route, $rootScope, ngDialog, czs, $sce, $q, user) {

//I want to send this information to MainActivity
$scope.dataForMainActivity = "Data to send";




    }]);
```

[image: Android Studio files]

> Can someone please write me an example code? I would be very grateful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create JavascriptWebInterface class. It can be an inner class.

   ```
   public class JsInterface {
     Context mContext;

     JsInterface(Context c) {
       mContext = c;
     }

     @JavascriptInterface   // << This annotation makes it works!
     public void myFunc(String toast) {
       Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
   }
   ```
2. Register that class to webView. Cordova hide it inside of appView.

   ```
   package at.restaurantKellner;


   import android.os.Bundle;
   import org.apache.cordova.*;

   public class MainActivity extends CordovaActivity
   {
       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
       {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           super.init(); //ADD super.init

           // enable Cordova apps to be started in the background
           Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
           if (extras != null && extras.getBoolean("cdvStartInBackground", false)) {
               moveTaskToBack(true);
           }

           // INJECT OUR JS INTERFACE HERE!
           WebView webView = (WebView) this.appView.getEngine().getView();
           webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
           webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JsInterface(webView.getContext()), "android");

           // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
           loadUrl(launchUrl);
       }
   }
   ```
3. Make a call as normal javascript call. Better to check if android exists. Note that the `android` is javascript object in the window. if you are in the inner scope of angular, you may need to access it via `window.android`.

   ```
   if (typeof android !== 'undefined' && android !== null) {
       android.myFunc('hello');
   } else {
       console.log('Not in android webbox');
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, unfortunately when I add this, app is crashed. Here is my android project: [ANdroid Project](http://adamovic.net/android.zip) Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: Add `super.init();` after `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

Comment: It works! Thank you.
I'm not good with Android, you saved my day.
In fact, I need to send JSON data to the SDK from the POS printer, to send it via Wifi to printer. If I need help, can I contact you here? 
Thanks a lot

Comment: @ExyuPortal glad I could help. You can post a question anytime. I believe there are many ppl here that can answer your question.

Comment: Hi digitake, I need help again. I do not know how to connect the  printer SDK with the application. Here is Android SDK for printer: [SDK Download](http://www.adamovic.net/Metapace.zip)   I need to connect the printer first `metapacePrinter = new MetapacePrinter(this, mHandler, null);
    String hostx;
    hostx = "192.168.1.25";
  metapacePrinter.connect(hostx, 9100, 5000);` then to send JSON data to the print, it's in PrintTextActivity class... private void printText()...  can you help me please?

Comment: Hi, Is there anyways we can do otherway round, I need to send contacts from Native to webview?